# Data is not adding in firebase from react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, crud

Hey i want to add data to firebase from my react app but i am getting error

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.22.2): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Write' stream 0x55ad5f60 transport errored:

How can I solve this issue?

code snippet that i am writing

```
await addDoc(collection(db,"users"),{
    ...data,
    timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
})
```